# Angular 5 'inputClick' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm new to angular and front end programming so I'm sorry if that is too easy.

I have an `HTML` file that looks like this

```
<input class="born-date-input" formControlName="dateOfBorn" minlength="1" maxlength="10" (click)="inputClick=true"/>
<div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="inputClick==true">
      <small>show warning</small>
</div>
```

In my component .ts file I have

```
export class MainInputFormComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  @Output('changeData') sendTheNewDataJSON = new EventEmitter<any>();

  private inputClick: boolean = false;
}
```

the `inputClick` variable is not seen in the HTML file

Comment: Declare it as public instead of private. `public inputClick: boolean = false;`

Comment: Thank you, now it works, but the "show warning" message is not showing when I click on the `input`. Why is that ?

Comment: Use `focus` instead of `click`. `(focus)="inputClick=true"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data binding will not happen if you declare it as private. You need to declare it as `public` to make it available. Follow the code below:

```
   export class MainInputFormComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
      @Output('changeData') sendTheNewDataJSON = new EventEmitter<any>();

      public inputClick: boolean = false;
    }
```

then you can use it in your HTML like this.

```
<input class="born-date-input" formControlName="dateOfBorn" minlength="1" maxlength="10" (click)="inputClick=true"/>
<div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="inputClick">
      <small>show warning</small>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I click on the `input`, the `div` is not showing the "show warning" message

Comment: Well it should work and it is working in my case, could you please update your code. So that we can debug it. Also please mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Comment: It worked, I was writing it in the wrong place, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Change 'private' to 'public' or remove access modifier (by default it is public)

```
export class MainInputFormComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
 @Output('changeData') sendTheNewDataJSON = new EventEmitter<any>();

 inputClick: boolean = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of these because inputClick cannot be accessed when it is declared private

```
 export class MainInputFormComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
 @Output('changeData') sendTheNewDataJSON = new EventEmitter<any>();

 inputClick: boolean = false;
}
```

or

```
export class MainInputFormComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
 @Output('changeData') sendTheNewDataJSON = new EventEmitter<any>();

 public inputClick: boolean = false;
}
```